# Grub gone. Usb boot and windows recovery both don't work

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, live-usb, grubrescue

I have an Asus Zenbook UX31E 128 gb ssd without CD reader. Time ago I installed ubuntu in parallel with windows7 dividing in half the ssd space and leaving the 2 small partitions of which one should be the recovery of windows. Yesterday I wanted to access the ubuntu partition using window to store file, so I used the ubuntu disk management utility to try change ubuntu partition to NTFS. I should not have done it at all.

Now at startup instead of the usual grub with purple background (should be the grub 2, isn't it? ) Grub rescue comes and gives me "error : no such partition" . I think the ubuntu partition is no longer recognizable (but I think it's still there, I just tried to change format and I have not seen progress bars with ongoing processes ) and the grub can not see his configuration file that is among the system files of ubuntu . I created a ubuntu usb stick with unetbootin to use grub -repair from there , so I choose as boot device UEFI:" key name " (there was also the option without UEFI but doesn't work) . Booting from USB seems to work , it opens "GNU GRUB version 1.99 - 21ubuntu3 .10 " with the options "try ubuntu without installing " , "install ubuntu" and "check for disk defects " but none of the three works, and bring all to a black screen with no chance to do something . In addition to the three options mentioned I can go to " edit the commands before booting" or command- line , from these two can I do something? 
Or do you advise me to try to re-download the iso of ubuntu and redo the key ?

At his point I decided to format the pc and factory restore it. When you switch on the pc with f9 pressed you should activate the windows recovery that allows to restore your computer running like new , but it doesn't work , I'm sure I've not deleted the partition. I think the windows recovery doesn't work because the grub problem is before the Ricovery. I should choose Windows from grub and then press f9 .

Finally, to the ls command typed in the command line grub made ​​from the stick I have: ( memdisk ) (hd0) (hd0, msdos5 ) (hd0, msdos1 ) ( hd1) ( hd1, msdos1 ) ( hd2 ) ( hd2 , msdos3 ) ( hd2 , msdos2 ) ( hd2 , msdos1 ) .

I thank anyone who has the patience to read . Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks. Francesco.

Answer (score 1):

You say couldn't use the *try Ubuntu* and other options, so make a fresh bootable USB stick again with the Ubuntu ISO you have (or download a new one), and try to boot to the live session and check if the system file structure is still there. If the files are good and the problem is just with the boot, install the `boot-repair` utility and use it to fix your system. Here's a link that will guide how you can install the utility in the live Ubuntu: [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

But if the formatting that you attempted previously deleted some other critical files or directory structures, which I suspect might be the case, you'll have to look forward to a fresh Ubuntu installation.